# Error in indicies while unsetting Sessions

Tags: php, session, indexing, undefined

While unsetting the session I am getting the error:

> Undefined Index

I have used 3 files: set.php unset.php and view.php

I am new to PHP programming. Please Help!

```
1. set.php:

<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = 'ayusch';

?>

2.unset.php
<?php
session_start();

unset($_SESSION['username']);

?>

3. view.php:
<?php

session_start();
echo 'Welcome  ' . $_SESSION['username'] . 'you are ' . $_SESSION['age'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2.unset.php
<?php
session_start();

unset($_SESSION['username']);

?>
```

change to this

```
2.unset.php
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

?>
```

read this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) for unset session

Comment: But this would end the entire session but i want to end only one session

Comment: i test your code it is working and destroy session without any error.